# Объекты характеристик. Как реализовать для объектов характеристик методы других характеристик?

Tags: rust

```rust
use std::io::Write;
 
fn t_object(x: &mut dyn Write) {
    
    x.write(&[6,7,8,9,10]).ok(); //все прекрасно - добавили элементы в вектор.
    println!("{:?}", x); //ошибка: характеристика std::fmt::Debug не реализована для типа dyn Write
 
}
 
fn main() {
    
    let mut x = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    
    t_object(&mut x);

}
```

Comment: Не встречал до этого термина "характеристика" для перевода trait. Есть какая-то литература, в которой перевели так?

Comment: Обязательно ли для функции t_object работать с динамическим объектом? Статическое обобщение позволяет ограничивать параметр типа произвольным набором типажей и будет скомпилировано в наиболее эффективный код при подстановке типа.

Comment: Когда в метод передается ссылка на интерфейс `std::io::Write`, то доступны методы этого интерфейса. Логично же. Если нужны методы еще какого-то интерфейса, то реализуйте собственный интерфейс, наследующий требуемые.

Answer (score 1):

Реализовать дополнительные типажи (так они называются в [переводе описания языка](https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch10-02-traits.html)), не определенные в том же крейте, нельзя в силу "сиротского правила". Также нельзя добавлять дополнительные типажи в тип динамического объекта, например, `(dyn Write + Debug)` (единственное исключение — автоматически реализуемые типажи вроде `Send`).

Если действительно нужен динамический объект с интерфейсом, объединяющим несколько типажей, можно ввести вспомогательный типаж:

```rust
trait MyInterface: Write + Debug {}

impl<T> MyInterface for T where T: Write + Debug {}

fn t_object(x: &mut dyn MyInterface) {
    x.write(&[6,7,8,9,10]).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```